# Structural induction: Every propositional formula without negation is true under interpretation

Tags: logic, solution-verification, induction, propositional-calculus

I have to proof the following statement.

> Let $L$ be a language of propositional logic where formulas are built only from atomic formulas using the primitive connectives $¬$, $∧$, $∨$, $→$, and $↔$.
>
> Let $A$ be a formula of $L$ containing no occurrence of $¬$ and $I$ an interpretation assigning to all atomic formulas of $A$ the truth value $1$.
>
> Then, $A$ is true under $I$.

I wanted to archieve this using structural induction and I would like somebody to review it.

> Let $P ⊆ L$ be a set containing propositional letters. The set $F$ of (propositional logic) formulas over $P$ without occurrence of $¬$ is defined recursively by:
>
> (1) If $p ∈ P$, then $p$ is a formula over $F$.
>
> (2) If $β$ and $γ$ are formulas over $F$, then so are:
>
> - ($β ∧ γ$)
> - ($β ∨ γ$)
> - ($β → γ$)
> - ($β ↔ γ$)
>
> Suppose there is an interpretation $I$ such that for every propositional letter $α ∈ P$ that $I(α) = 1$.
>
> Then the following holds:
>
> (1) If $p ∈ P$, then $I(p) = 1$.
>
> (2) Assume $β, γ ∈ F$ and $I(β) = I(γ) = 1$. 
>   Therefore the following applies for $β, γ ∈ F$.
>
> - $I(β ∧ γ) = 1$
> - $I(β ∨ γ) = 1$
> - $I(β → γ) = 1$
> - $I(β ↔ γ) = 1$
>
> Therefore $A ∈ F$ is true under $I$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem rather confused about how structural induction works.  If you want to prove a statement $S(\alpha)$ is true for any $\alpha\in F$, you need to do the following two steps.

First, you need to prove that $S(\alpha)$ is true if $\alpha\in P$.  This is the "base case" of the induction, if you like.

Second, you need to prove that if $\alpha$ has the form $\beta\wedge\gamma$, $\beta\vee\gamma$, $\beta\rightarrow\gamma$, or $\beta\leftrightarrow\gamma$ where $\beta,\gamma\in F$ **and $S(\beta)$ and $S(\gamma)$ are true**, then $S(\alpha)$ is true.  The assumption that $S(\beta)$ and $S(\gamma)$ are true is the induction hypothesis: you are assuming the result already holds for the formulas in $F$ you have built up "so far", and using that to conclude that it also holds for your new formula $\alpha$.

In your case, the statement $S(\alpha)$ is "$I(\alpha)=1$".  The first step is what you did in your step (1).  But you have not done the second step yet!  You asserted that $I(\beta\wedge\gamma)=1$, $I(\beta\vee\gamma)=1$, and so on are true for $\beta,\gamma\in F$, but you never gave any proof of these assertions.  To complete the second step, you need to **assume** the induction hypothesis that $\beta,\gamma\in F$ and $I(\beta)=I(\gamma)=1$, and then use that to **prove** that $I(\beta\vee\gamma)=1$ and so on.  In your step (2), you did that in the special case that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are in $P$, but you need to do it for arbitrary elements of $F$ (given the induction hypothesis).

Comment: I have updated my post and added an additional hypothesis. Is it correct now? I am unsure about that part.

Comment: No, you still have given no explanation whatsoever for your step (3).  You need to state an induction hypothesis and then use that induction hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support!